# Swift2 - HKSampleQuery

Tags: swift2, healthkit, hksamplequery

```
let hkSampleType:HKSampleType = HKSampleType.correlationTypeForIdentifier(HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierFood)!
let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: hkSampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: 80, sortDescriptors: nil, resultsHandler: { (query:HKSampleQuery, results:[HKSample]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    //code
})
```

this is it but I receive an error: `Cannot find an initializer for type 'HKSampleQuery' that accepts an argument list of type '(sampleType: HKSampleType, predicate: NSPredicate, limit: Int, sortDescriptors: nil, resultsHandler: (HKSampleQuery, [HKSample]!, NSError!) -> Void)'`

How will be the right syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in either Swift or HealthKit, but this compiles in Xcode 7:

```
let hkSampleType:HKSampleType = HKSampleType.correlationTypeForIdentifier(HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierFood)!
let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: hkSampleType, predicate: nil, limit: 80, sortDescriptors: nil, resultsHandler: { (query:HKSampleQuery, results:[HKSample]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    //code
})
```

In the closure, `results` and `error` are optionals in iOS 9. You declared them as unwrapped.

One thing I'm not sure about is that can you use `HKSampleQuery` for `HKCorrelation`. Here is the correct declaration for `HKCorrelationQuery` in case you need it:

```
let corralationType = HKCorrelationType.correlationTypeForIdentifier(HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierFood)!
let query = HKCorrelationQuery(type: corralationType, predicate: nil, samplePredicates: nil) { (query: HKCorrelationQuery, results: [HKCorrelation]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

}
```